# How to use turtle.onclick with an object from a class?

Tags: python, methods, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, python-class

I want to make a class for turtle buttons and have a field to be the turtle
and here is the code I wrote:

```
class button:
  def __init__(self,color,x,y):
     self.turtle=turtle.Turtle()
     self.turtle.penup()
     self.turtle.shape("square")
     self.turtle.color(color)
     self.turtle.speed(0)
     self.turtle.goto(x,y)
```

Now I want to use the `onclick` to a button instance, so how do I do that is it something like this?

```
  def click(self,x,y):
     print ("hello world")
     self.turtle.onclick()
```

I'm not that good at classes btw so I just want something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to bind the class' `click()` method to mouse-click events. See the documentation for the [`turtle.onclick()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onclick) method.

```
import turtle

SCREENWIDTH = 640
SCREENHEIGHT = 480

class Button:
    def __init__(self,color,x,y):
        self.turtle = turtle.Turtle()
        self.turtle.penup()
        self.turtle.shape("square")
        self.turtle.color(color)
        self.turtle.speed(0)
        self.turtle.goto(x,y)
        self.turtle.onclick(self.click)  # Bind mouse-click event to method.

    def click(self, x, y):
        print ("hello world")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainscreen = turtle.Screen()
    mainscreen.mode("standard")
    mainscreen.setup(SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT)
    Button('red', 0, 0)
    turtle.mainloop()
```

P.S. I strongly suggest you read and start following the coding suggestions in the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It will make your code easier to read and understand.